# Nodejs send data in headers using request

Tags: node.js, header, request

The server only accepts data sent in the headers.

Doing it using this code the server is getting empty object:

```
const request = require('request')
request.post({
    url: 'https://.....',
    body: { userid: 'cris', gameid: '12' },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
})
```

Doing it with Postman, the server gets the correct data:
[image]

**How can i use the code to send the data in the headers?**

---

**Edit:**

> A printscreen with server info displayed in the browser, should help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 const request = require('request')
 request.post({
   url: 'https://.....',
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain', 'userid':'cris', 'gameid':'12'}
})
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer`

Comment: same thing :(. i hate Headers ><

Comment: if the body is not required then remove it.

Comment: Removing the body completely, worked with your example! Thanks Mustafa!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 const request = require('request')
   request.post({
   url: 'https://.....',
   body: JSON.stringify({ userid: 'cris', gameid: '12' }),
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
})
```

Comment: Same empty object. I didn't think about stringify. I was thinking to send somehow in the headers property, or another specific property that i can't find :-/

Comment: I found some browser info about the server and attached it to the question. It sais it accepts text, but stringify doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body: { "userid": "cris", "gameid": "12" }
```

Comment: It's saying error, first argument must be string or buffer. Also tried `body: JSON.stringify({ "userid": "cris", "gameid": "12" }),` with same empty object result.

Comment: I have tried with this , it is working  ```const request = require('request')
request.post({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/test',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    body: "{ userid: 'cris', gameid: '12' }"

  
},function(err,res){

 console.log(res)
})```

Comment: If i send the same data in the `body` using Postman `x-www-form-urlencoded` , the server is getting the same empty object.